# Network Service account cannot see SQLServer performance counters on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, performance-counters

I have a service running on a large number of servers, that logs Windows Performance Counters to a central logging system. The service is written in .Net, and runs as the build-in account "Network Service".

This works fine on Windows 2003, but on Windows 2008 R2 the service cannot see any instances in the "SQLServer:Databases" category, or any of the other SQLServer categories. If i change the service to run as a local administrator, it sees the instances just fine.

For all non-SQLServer categories (e.g. LogicalDisk), Network Service can see the instances just fine.

Is it possible to set up the access rights, so that Network Service can see the performance counter instances? Or can anyone explain this difference between Windows 2005 and 2008 R2?

SQL Server version is 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access these by adding NETWORK SERVICE to the local Performance Monitor Users group...

Comment: Thanks. That solved it :-)

Quite obvious when you think about it - but apparently not obvious enough that I came up with it :-P